# Weird error when executing MSSQL prepared query

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, odbc

I've got an issue with odbc_* functions. This is the first query I've had the issues with. 
I have the following code:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('DSN', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "
    SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS a 
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS c 
        ON c.StudentId = a.StudentId 
            AND c.ContactId = ? 
            AND c.SetId = a.SetId 
    WHERE a.SetId = ? 
");

$result = odbc_execute($stmt, array('14153', '2013/2014'));
```

This however, produces the error:

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter number, SQL state S1093 in SQLDescribeParameter
```

If I remve the `c.ContactId = ?` and dont bind the value `14153`, then the query works fine.

However I bind the same value on another query and it works fine!

Does anyone know what this error indicates? 
Many thanks

Comment: Looks like you are passing in a parameter that should be an integer? (`SetId`)

Comment: The `2013/2014` parameter works fine, its the `14153` parameter that's not binding, but I've tried binding it without the quotes and still produces the same error unfortunately :(, and also in the database, the SetId field is defined as a text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Invalid parameter number, SQL state S1093 in
>   SQLDescribeParameter

There are a number of strange things about this. Firstly there is no ODBC 3 API SQLDescribeParameter, it is [SQLDescribeParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then there is your error state S1093 which is an ODBC 2 state which is [mapped](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/sqlstate_mappings.html) to 07009 in ODBC 3.

Error 07009 means the parameter number passed to SQLDescribeParam was wrong i.e., in your case not 1 or 2 so that suggests the underlying ODBC support in PHP has made a mistake or SQLNumParams returned the wrong number of parameters.

I'm aware of an issue with SQLDescribeParam with the SQL Server driver. In order to support SQLDescribeParam the driver reorganizes your SQL into a 'select p1_column, p2_column from table'. Sometimes the driver gets the reorganization wrong (see [this faq entry](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.43/FAQ#Why_am_I_getting_errors_with_bound_parameters?) and look down for data truncated error).

I don't do PHP these days or have anything more to do with ODBC support in PHP but I'd suggest you get an ODBC trace from your ODBC driver manager and that might help identify the problem.